# Unable to fetch the custom properties from AWS secret manager for micronaut application invoked by AWS lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, micronaut, aws-sdk-java-2.0, micronaut-aws

I am getting below error :
Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to secretsmanager.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com:443 [secretsmanager.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ipadress, secretsmanager.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ipadress] failed: connect timed out", "errorType": "software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException"

Fetch the custom properties from AWS secret manager which is located under secret name: /config/micronautguide/details and encryption by using aws/secretmanager and created key/value pair as: `menuEventTest: testingData`

I have a micronaut application which is executed by AWS lambda function.
Below are the code details:

bootstrap.yml

```
 micronaut:
      config-client:
        enabled: true
      application:
        name: micronautguide
 aws:
      secretsmanager:
        secrets:
          - secret-name: /config/micronautguide/details
```

application.yml

```
menuEventTest: ${menuEventTest}
```

MicronautCode:

```
public class FunctionRequestHandler extends MicronautRequestHandler<Object, Object> {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FunctionRequestHandler.class);
  @Value("${menuEventTest}")
  private String menuEventTest;
  @Override
  public Object execute(Object payload) {
   
    LOG.info("Request menuEvent: {} ", menuEventTest);
    }
```

I followed the link:
[micronaut aws configuration](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-aws/3.10.9/guide/index.html#distributedconfiguration)

Required Dependencies:

```
implementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-aws-secretsmanager")
 implementation("io.micronaut.aws:micronaut-function-aws")
```

how to fetch the properties from secret manager for micronaut application.

Comment: Yes, Due to role issues  and IAM policy is not added properly to my lambda function

Comment: I have created question, please take a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76860089/micronaut-framework-connect-to-aws-secret-manager-is-failed-when-calling-from