# Micronaut Framework - Connect to AWS secret manager is failed when calling from AWS lambda

Tags: micronaut, aws-secrets-manager, micronaut-aws

I have stored values in AWS secret manager using secret name : `config/awsservices/db`. I want to fetch these values using Micronaut framework. below the the configuration -

bootstrap.yml

```
micronaut:
  config-client:
    enabled: true
  application:
    name: awsservices
  
aws:
  secretsmanager:
    secrets:
      - secret-name: /config/awsservices/db
```

application.yml

```
username: ${username}
```

Micronaut code:

```
public class FunctionRequestHandler extends MicronautRequestHandler<APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent, APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent> {
    
    @Value("${username}")
    public String username;
    
    @Override
    public APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent execute(APIGatewayProxyRequestEvent input) {
        System.out.println("-------------- Inside Main Function -------------");
        APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent response = new APIGatewayProxyResponseEvent();
        try {
            
            System.out.println("-- username : "+username);
            response.setStatusCode(200);
            response.setBody("");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            response.setStatusCode(500);
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

In the logs, i am getting username is `null`.

How to fetch values from secret manager?

Comment: remove this aws.secretsmanager.secrets from yml and give a try